# Matching postegresSQL foreign key with the primary key using R

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I've 2 tables in my postegreSQL database

```
CREATE TABLE touriste (
idclient BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
numclient INT,
nameclient VARCHAR(500),
codepost INT,
departement VARCHAR(500),
pays VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE reservation (
idresa BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(idresa),
dateresa DATE,
datearriv DATE,
datedep DATE,
idclient_cli BIGINT
    REFERENCES touriste (idclient) MATCH FULL ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
);
```

I tried to fullfill the database tables with my dataframe (which is already created in R) by using RPostgreSQL library. The probleme is that the column idclient_cli is empty.

Here is my R code :

```
dbWriteTable(con, "touriste", 
         value = dataAdb[, c(2:4, 17:19)], append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
# query the data from postgreSQL 
df_postgres_tou <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from touriste")
View(df_postgres_tou)

dbWriteTable(con, "reservation", 
         value = dataAdb[, c(5:7, 14, 12, 13, 15:16, 20)], append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
# query the data from postgreSQL 
df_postgres_resa <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from reservation")
View(df_postgres_resa)
```

My question is how can I match `idclient` value with the `idclient_cli`

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Since you do not show the data but use numbered index of columns, does your second `dbWriteTable` actually have a column named `idclient_cli` with integers populated? Postgres cannot automatically populate data but only imposes constraints on allowable values. Also, you pass in more columns in each data frame than corresponding columns in table (i.e., 6 vs 5 and 9 vs 4 -leaving out serial primary keys). Finally, in R, how do the two data frames relate?

Comment: In this example I didn't put all columns in my database tables but I have more columns than that. And no I haven't a **idclient_cli** in my dataframe if it's what you want to say.

Comment: Ok. So how do the two data frames relate? What logic can we use to assign `idclient_cli`? In other words, how are tourists identified in the reservations data?

Comment: I find a way to do that